# Error using rename and summarize together in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I am using a dplyr 0.74 and rlang 0.20. 
With the code below, i want to examine and visualise median frequency across segment but i get rename code

```
rfm_plot <- rfm_class_group %>%
  group_by(Segment) %>%
  select(Segment, Frequency) %>%
  summarize(median(Frequency)) %>%
  rename(segmented = Segment, avg_frequency = median(Frequency)) %>%
  arrange(avg_frequency)
```

> **Error: Expressions are currently not supported in `rename()`**

I have even tried `plyr::rename(segmented =...)` still to no avail.

Desired result:

```
    Segmented         avg_frequency
    Champions                  67.5
    Loyalists                    43
    Promising                     7
      Churned                     5
```

Comment: put avg_frequency inside the summarize statement instead of in the rename statement.

Comment: .... because it's a very good and useful practice to give a name to whatever you calculate with summarize, so you can easily use it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dplyr::rename` instead.

And generally, in case you really need `plyr`, you should load it before `dplyr`.